# How can I send a calculated value to a cell and save the sheet so that when reopened the cell has no formula attached?

Tags: excel

I need to read (never edit) a fancy excel sheet in google docs but google docs doesn't support all the formulas that excel does. I need to have excel send calculated values to certain cells and save them there as just raw values automatically, so google docs will display the values when I open it there on my phone.

You might say I'm trying to push values to certain cells rather than pull the values using formulas in those certain cells.

Is it possible? Is this question clear enough?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the cell with formula and paste it back as value again to remove the formula and retain it's value.

OR you may use VBA to do it for you if you have bunch of cells with formulas in them and you want to automate it.
For this purpose you can use an event called Workbook_BeforeSave so that when you save your work, the formulas will be converted into the values. So next time when you open your excel workbook whether in excel application or in google spreadsheet, you won't find any formulas in those cells.

If you go with the VBA solution, you will need to save your workbook as Macro-Enabled Workbook.

To implement the suggested event code into your workbook, follow these steps...

1. Open your file.
2. Press Alt+F11 to open VB Editor.
3. On VB Editor --> Double click ThisWorkbook from the project explorer on left side and paste the code given below into the opened code window.
4. Close the VB Editor and save your workbook as Macro-Enabled Workbook.

In the code below, change the ranges as per your requirement.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

'you can convert formula in a cell to value like below
Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value

'if you have a range of cells with formula, you can try like below
Range("A2:A10").Value = Range("A2:A10").Value

End Sub
```